# Put all serilog in links in class library and other projects use class library dll as reference not working. Is this possible

Tags: c#, serilog

I need to use Serilog in a number of projects in both .Net Framework and Core. It would be nice if all the Serilog nuget references could be in link to one DLL and that DLL could referenced to use Serilog.
Is this possible?
From trying it, it does not seem possible.
Any ideas how this could be achieved?

I created a class library and installed the Serilog Nuget references into that class library, and then proceeded to compile the class library to produce a DLL.
When other projects would reference to this DLL the Serilog references in the DLL could found.

if a.Net Core (.Net 6)  class library was included as reference project in .Net Core project the Serilog references could be found by that project.

The same was not true for .Net Framework 4.8. If the .Net Framework 4.8 class library was included in a reference project in a  .Net Framework 4.8 project the Serilog references could not be found by the project. Is there something that can be done so the Serilog references could be found?

Comment: What is the target framework for the shared library project?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refer serilog in every class library. You can use interface. I've created a class called SerilogWrapper that implements the ILogger interface. This class serves as a wrapper over Serilog, and you can now use the ILogger interface to interact with your logging methods.
Example

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void LogInformation(string information);

    void LogError(string information);

    void LogError(Exception ex, String msgException);

    void LogFlush();
}

public class SerilogWrapper : ILogger
{
    public void LogInformation(string information)
    {
        Log.Information(information);
    }

    public void LogError(string information)
    {
        Log.Error(information);
    }

    public void LogError(Exception ex, String msgException)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, msgException);
    }

    public void LogFlush()
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

**Now, the SomeClassUsingLogger class does not directly reference Serilog. It relies on the ILogger interface, making it more flexible. You can easily switch to a different logging framework in the future without modifying the SomeClassUsingLogger class.**

Comment: I think you missed the point or did not understand the question.  There is NO code in the .Net 6 class library. There are only references to the Serilog Nuget packages. The .Net 6 class library is referenced in other projects that want to use Serilog. Using your suggestion would just be reinventing the wheel and I would have to maintain the code for other projects which is a pain in the butt and not what I want to do. The other projects can create the Serilog Logger and use it however they want, or the main application could use dependency injection for the Serilog Logger interface